# How to get data to a Windows form when database is updated?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to write a C# application, when database get updated, that record data should be stored in an array. I have no idea to do that. How to get the updated record to my application at the same time updating is happend.
I use MySQL database

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea about how to get updated data at the same time, when that updating is happened.Without any btn clk event,, When the updating is happened my windows form should be received those updated record data

Comment: @Randi how is the database being updated? Is your app updating the database or is something else updating the database?

Comment: Database is updating via a web service connected to an android application.When update the database that newly entered record should be caught by my windows client application,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I've misread your questions, but I believe you're looking for a way for your application to know what the database is changed by something other than your form?

Detecting external data updates is a significant architectural question.  To get "push" notifications you would need to either have a data service that acts as your data store and simply persists the data back to the database or use some sort of notification mechanism in MySQL itself, which I do not believe is natively supported (and generally is not a great idea).

Your other option would be to have a polling loop on the UI side to check for changes periodically. Also not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited based on your comment)

Take a look at MVVM mapping to database (try googling that). 
Here is an example that looks ok - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124160/Using-WPF-MVVM-for-Database-Access.

There are plenty of examples that show up if you search the given search terms.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to establish a connection between your C# app and your mysql database.  This is usally done with a `MySqlConnection` which you use to execute a `MySqlCommand`.  [Take a look at this article](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html) for the code and a description of the process.